# How to make a test in stylus?

Tags: rust, stylus

Let's say I have the following stylus contract:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "export-abi"), no_main)]
extern crate alloc;
use stylus_sdk::{
    alloy_primitives::U256,
    prelude::{entrypoint, external, sol_storage},
};


sol_storage! {
    #[entrypoint]
    pub struct SimpleStorage {
        uint256 my_favorite_number;
    }
}

#[external]
impl SimpleStorage {
    pub fn store(&mut self, new_number: U256) -> Result<(), Vec<u8>> {
        self.my_favorite_number.set(new_number);
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn retrieve(&self) -> Result<U256, Vec<u8>> {
        Ok(self.my_favorite_number.get())
    }
}
```

How would I write a unit test for this? Where would I put the unit test?